Adding map to empty map frame in print layout of QGIS
In QGIS, I have created a print layout with a map frame for which I specified the size. When I now load a certain qgis project with data in it, and then create a new print layout from that template for the new project, the map frame stays empty. I could now use the empty map frame to create a new map with that empty map frame size, but there must be a more convenient way.
How can I now add my data view into that empty map frame?


I figured out, that I had to use the button 'Set map extent to match main canvas extent' as well as the refresh under Map Item Properties header. Now the map is shown in the relavent Map item.
Make also sure that the data is actually in the data view.


Check your CRS if its correct,
Try using LIMA version of QGIS or the latest one, or try to zoom to layer unless otherwise you should try to save your files and create another project and load the data to the other project and that surely this was my last option which always work but it's time consuming since you have to load data again and edit what's to be edited.
